# How does gganimate order an ordered bar time-series?

Tags: r, animation, ggplot2, dplyr, gganimate

I have a time-series of data, where I'm plotting diagnosis rates for a disease on the y-axis `DIAG_RATE_65_PLUS`, and geographical groups for comparison on the x-axis `NAME` as a simple bar graph. My time variable is `ACH_DATEyearmon`, which the animation is cycling through as seen in the title.

```
df %>% ggplot(aes(reorder(NAME, DIAG_RATE_65_PLUS), DIAG_RATE_65_PLUS)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", alpha = 0.66) +
  labs(title='{closest_state}') +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 1, size = 22),
        axis.text.x=element_blank()) +
  transition_states(ACH_DATEyearmon, transition_length = 1, state_length = 1) +
  ease_aes('linear')
```

I've reordered `NAME` so it gets ranked by `DIAG_RATE_65_PLUS`.

What gganimate produces:

[image: gganimate plot]

I now have two questions:

1) How exactly does gganimate reorder the data? There is some overall general reordering, but each month has no frame where the groups are perfectly ordered by `DIAG_RATE_65_PLUS` from smallest to biggest. Ideally, I would like the final month "Aug 2018" to be ordered perfectly. All of the previous months can have their x-axis based on the ordered `NAME` for "Aug 2018`.

2) Is there an option in gganimate where the groups "shift" to their correct rank for each month in the bar chart?

Plots for my comment queries:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2UPw.gif
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1wfd.gif

**@JonSpring**

```
    df %>%
  ggplot(aes(ordering, group = NAME)) +
  geom_tile(aes(y = DIAG_RATE_65_PLUS/2, 
                height = DIAG_RATE_65_PLUS,
                width = 0.9), alpha = 0.9, fill = "gray60") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = (2/3)*25, linetype="dotdash") +
  # text in x-axis (requires clip = "off" in coord_cartesian)
  geom_text(aes(y = 0, label = NAME), hjust = 2) + ## trying different hjust values
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 1, size = 22),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), ## axis.ticks.y shows the ticks on the flipped x-axis (the now metric), and hides the ticks from the geog layer
        axis.text.y = element_blank()) + ## axis.text.y shows the scale on the flipped x-axis (the now metric), and hides the placeholder "ordered" numbers from the geog layer
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off", expand = FALSE) +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(title='{closest_state}', x = "") +
  transition_states(ACH_DATEyearmon, 
                    transition_length = 2, state_length = 1) +
  ease_aes('cubic-in-out')
```

With `hjust=2`, labels are not aligned and move around.

[image]

Changing the above code with `hjust=1`

[image]

**@eipi10**

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y=NAME, x=DIAG_RATE_65_PLUS)) +
  geom_barh(stat = "identity", alpha = 0.66) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=(2/3)*25, linetype = "dotdash") + #geom_vline(xintercept=(2/3)*25) is incompatible, but geom_hline works, but it's not useful for the plot
  labs(title='{closest_state}') +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 1, size = 22)) +
  transition_states(ACH_DATEyearmon, transition_length = 1, state_length = 50) +
  view_follow(fixed_x=TRUE) +
  ease_aes('linear')
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of your actual data? It's possible we can suggest alternatives to an animated bar graph that might work better with your data.

Comment: @eipi10 the df you generated pretty much reproduces the df I'm working with perfectly, but I've pasted a small subset of my data to pastebin [here](https://pastebin.com/V02zyX4Q).

With your last edit, is there any way to incorporate a `geom_vline`? It doesn't seem like it's compatible with `ggstance` geoms, but `geom_hline` works for some reason but it's not useful for my plot. Added code to my question.

Comment: One hack for adding some spacing to right-justified labels is to use `hjust = 1` and also change the label to `aes(label = paste(country, "   "))` so that they're right aligned but with extra spaces. There seems to be a bug for `hjust > 1`. See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53162821/animated-sorted-bar-chart-with-bars-overtaking-each-other/53163549#53163549

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The bar ordering is done by `ggplot` and is not affected by `gganimate`. The bars are being ordered based on the sum of `DIAG_RATE_65_PLUS` within each `ACH_DATEyearmon`. Below I'll show how the bars are ordered and then provide code for creating the animated plot with the desired sorting from low to high in each frame.

To see how the bars are ordered, first let's create some fake data:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gganimate)
theme_set(theme_classic())

# Fake data
dates = paste(rep(month.abb, each=10), 2017)

set.seed(2)
df = data.frame(NAME=c(replicate(12, sample(LETTERS[1:10]))),
                ACH_DATEyearmon=factor(dates, levels=unique(dates)),
                DIAG_RATE_65_PLUS=c(replicate(12, rnorm(10, 30, 5))))
```

Now let's make a single bar plot. The bars are the sum of `DIAG_RATE_65_PLUS` for each `NAME`. Note the order of the x-axis `NAME` values:

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(reorder(NAME, DIAG_RATE_65_PLUS), DIAG_RATE_65_PLUS)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", alpha = 0.66) +
  labs(title='{closest_state}') +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 1, size = 22))
```

[image]

You can see below that the ordering is the same when we explicitly sum `DIAG_RATE_65_PLUS` by `NAME` and sort by the sum:

```
df %>% group_by(NAME) %>% 
  summarise(DIAG_RATE_65_PLUS = sum(DIAG_RATE_65_PLUS)) %>% 
  arrange(DIAG_RATE_65_PLUS)
```

> ```
>    NAME DIAG_RATE_65_PLUS
> 1     A          336.1271
> 2     H          345.2369
> 3     B          346.7151
> 4     I          350.1480
> 5     E          356.4333
> 6     C          367.4768
> 7     D          368.2225
> 8     F          368.3765
> 9     J          368.9655
> 10    G          387.1523
> ```

Now we want to create an animation that sorts `NAME` by `DIAG_RATE_65_PLUS` separately for each `ACH_DATEyearmon`. To do this, let's first generate a new column called `order` that sets the ordering we want:

```
df = df %>% 
  arrange(ACH_DATEyearmon, DIAG_RATE_65_PLUS) %>% 
  mutate(order = 1:n())
```

Now we create the animation. `transition_states` generates the frames for each `ACH_DATEyearmon`. `view_follow(fixed_y=TRUE)`shows x-values only for the current `ACH_DATEyearmon` and maintains the same y-axis range for all frames.

Note that we use `order` as the x variable, but then we run `scale_x_continuous` to change the x-labels to be the `NAME` values. I've included these labels in the plot so you can see that they change with each `ACH_DATEyearmon`, but you can of course remove them in your actual plot as you did in your example.

```
p = df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(order, DIAG_RATE_65_PLUS)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", alpha = 0.66) +
    labs(title='{closest_state}') +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 1, size = 22)) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=df$order, labels=df$NAME) +
    transition_states(ACH_DATEyearmon, transition_length = 1, state_length = 50) +
    view_follow(fixed_y=TRUE) +
    ease_aes('linear')

animate(p, nframes=60)

anim_save("test.gif")
```

[image]

If you turn off `view_follow()`, you can see what the "whole" plot looks like (and you can, of course, see the full, non-animated plot by stopping the code before the `transition_states` line).

```
p = df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(order, DIAG_RATE_65_PLUS)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", alpha = 0.66) +
    labs(title='{closest_state}') +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 1, size = 22)) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=df$order, labels=df$NAME) +
    transition_states(ACH_DATEyearmon, transition_length = 1, state_length = 50) +
    #view_follow(fixed_y=TRUE) +
    ease_aes('linear')
```

[image]

**UPDATE**: To answer your questions...

To order by a given month's values, turn the data into a factor with the levels ordered by that month. To plot a rotated graph, instead of `coord_flip`, we'll use `geom_barh` (horizontal bar plot) from the `ggstance` package. Note that we have to switch the y's and x's in `aes` and `view_follow()` and that the order of the y-axis `NAME` values is now constant:

```
library(ggstance)

# Set NAME order based on August 2017 values
df = df %>% 
  arrange(DIAG_RATE_65_PLUS) %>% 
  mutate(NAME = factor(NAME, levels=unique(NAME[ACH_DATEyearmon=="Aug 2017"])))

p = df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y=NAME, x=DIAG_RATE_65_PLUS)) +
  geom_barh(stat = "identity", alpha = 0.66) +
  labs(title='{closest_state}') +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 1, size = 22)) +
  transition_states(ACH_DATEyearmon, transition_length = 1, state_length = 50) +
  view_follow(fixed_x=TRUE) +
  ease_aes('linear')

animate(p, nframes=60)
anim_save("test3.gif")
```

[image]

For smooth transitions, it seems like @JonSpring's answer handles that well.

Comment: Thanks, this is a really novel (and AFAIK only) approach to my problem. For completion's sake, how would I be able to animate my graphs so the x-axis is ordered by the Aug 2018 values for NAME only, and maintaining this order for the rest of the months? This is probably a more general dplyr problem but it's still perplexing me.

Comment: In addition, any way to incorporate `coord_flip()`? With both my graph and using your data, the frames from the axis labels and ticks flash constantly.

Comment: Sorry one last question, I've tried extending the number of frames so the transition becomes smooth, but the x axis text seems to rotate out of the plot for each month. Is there a function so the text doesn't transit out when cycling through the months?

Edit: Added plot in starting post.

Answer (score 12):

To add on to @eipi10's great answer, I think this is a case where it's worth replacing `geom_bar` for more flexibility. `geom_bar` is normally quite convenient for discrete categories, but it doesn't let us take full advantage of `gganimate`'s silky-smooth animation glory.

For instance, with `geom_tile`, we can recreate the same appearance as geom_bar, but with fluid movement on the x-axis. This helps to keep visual track of each bar and to see which bars are shifting order the most. I think this addresses the 2nd part of your question nicely.

[image]

To make this work, we can add to the data a new column showing the ordering that should be used at each month. We save this order as a double, not an integer (by using`* 1.0`). This will allow `gganimate` to place a bar at position 1.25 when it's animating between position 1 and 2.

```
df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(ACH_DATEyearmon) %>%
  mutate(ordering = min_rank(DIAG_RATE_65_PLUS) * 1.0) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Now we can plot in similar fashion, but using `geom_tile` instead of `geom_bar`. I wanted to show the `NAME` both on top and at the axis, so I used two `geom_text` calls with different y values, one at zero and one at the height of the bar. `vjust` lets us align each vertically using text line units.

The other trick here is to turn off clipping in `coord_cartesian`, which lets the bottom text go below the plot area, into where the x-axis text would usually go.

```
p <- df2 %>%
  ggplot(aes(ordering, group = NAME)) +

  geom_tile(aes(y = DIAG_RATE_65_PLUS/2, 
                height = DIAG_RATE_65_PLUS,
                width = 0.9), alpha = 0.9, fill = "gray60") +
  # text on top of bars
  geom_text(aes(y = DIAG_RATE_65_PLUS, label = NAME), vjust = -0.5) +
  # text in x-axis (requires clip = "off" in coord_cartesian)
  geom_text(aes(y = 0, label = NAME), vjust = 2) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off", expand = FALSE) +

  labs(title='{closest_state}', x = "") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 1, size = 22),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x  = element_blank()) + 

  transition_states(ACH_DATEyearmon, 
                    transition_length = 2, state_length = 1) +
  ease_aes('cubic-in-out')

animate(p, nframes = 300, fps = 20, width = 400, height = 300)
```

---

Back to your first question, here's a color version that I made by removing `fill = "gray60"` from the `geom_tile` call. I sorted the `NAME` categories in order of Aug 2017, so they will look sequential for that one, as you described.

There's probably a better way to do that sorting, but I did it by joining `df2` to a table with just the Aug 2017 ordering.

[image]

```
Aug_order <- df %>%
  filter(ACH_DATEyearmon == "Aug 2017") %>%
  mutate(Aug_order = min_rank(DIAG_RATE_65_PLUS) * 1.0) %>%
  select(NAME, Aug_order)

df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(ACH_DATEyearmon) %>%
  mutate(ordering = min_rank(DIAG_RATE_65_PLUS) * 1.0) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  left_join(Aug_order) %>%
  mutate(NAME = fct_reorder(NAME, -Aug_order))
```

Comment: Thanks, this is almost perfect for what I need. Is there a way to incorporate coord_flip() with this? I have tried eipi10's edited comment, but this isn't compatible with geom_vline for some reason.

I've edited in my attempt at incorporating coord_flip() and a geom line. I want the labels of the bars to be to the left of the y-axis like in a standard ggplot.

Comment: Mind in my full df the labels are a lot longer, if it makes any difference.

Comment: I gave this a go with another question that wanted an animated horizontal bar plot: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53162821/animated-sorted-bar-chart-with-bars-overtaking-each-other/53163549#53163549