# Bar chart race with bars overtaking each other in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, bar-chart

How do I make bars over take each others in a sorted bar chart race ?
Basically the same as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53162821/animated-sorted-bar-chart-with-bars-overtaking-each-other), just in python.

My minimal bar chart race code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import matplotlib.animation as animation

data = np.abs(np.random.randn(200, 3))
ind = ['a', 'b', 'c']
data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=ind)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(16, 6.5))
# ax.barh(ind, data[0, :], color=['r', 'g', 'b'])
def getTopXY(data, i):
    top = data.iloc[i, :].T.sort_values(ascending=False)[::-1]
    return top.values, top.index

def update(i):
    ax.clear()
    X, Y = getTopXY(data, i)
    ax.barh(Y, X, color=['r', 'g', 'b'])
    
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,
                              update,
                              frames=len(data),
                              interval=10,
                              blit=False)
plt.show()
```

Comment: [Towards Data Science: Bar Chart Race in Python with Matplotlib](https://towardsdatascience.com/bar-chart-race-in-python-with-matplotlib-8e687a5c8a41)

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney the article doesn't have overtaking bars, look at the answers in the similar question I linked

Comment: You can try: https://github.com/dexplo/bar_chart_race

Comment: @SandervandenOord Thanks, just what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can try:
[github.com/dexplo/bar_chart_race](https://github.com/dexplo/bar_chart_race)

You can install via pip, but that's an older version 0.1.0:
`pip install bar_chart_race`

But it's better to install the latest version. You can do that as follows:
`pip install git+https://github.com/dexplo/bar_chart_race`