# How to make A racing Bar Chart in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I have a dataset that has a column of years from 1965 to 2020 and Teams that have won the championship in the respective years.

I am trying to create a racing bar chart and so far I have been struggling to create the required dataset to create the animated GIF

```
  df1 <- df %>% 
     group_by(Team) %>% 
     mutate(cups = 1:n()) %>% 
     ungroup() %>% 
     group_by(Year) %>% spread(Year, cups) %>% 
     replace(is.na(.),0)
```

which brings a result of the following format. [image]

Kindly assist in how I should go about completing this racing bar chart as I have browsed through several resources but I still cant seem to crack it..

Comment: please provide a reprex

Comment: I'd pivot the data into long format using `tidyr` with`%>% pivot_longer(-Team) %>% ` and then here's an approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53162821/animated-sorted-bar-chart-with-bars-overtaking-each-other/53163549#53163549

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this works, as Jon mentioned you need to pivot your data using `pivot_longer` from `tidyr`.

```
df1 <- pivot_longer(df, -1, names_to = 'Year') %>%
  rename(Team= ï..Team) %>%
  mutate(Year = as.numeric(substr(Year, 2, 5)))
```

Then this should create the racing barchart"

```
df1 <- df1 %>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
  # The * 1 makes it possible to have non-integer ranks while sliding
  mutate(rank = min_rank(-value) * 1,
         Value_rel = value/value[rank==1],
         Value_lbl = paste0(" ",value)) %>%
  filter(rank <=10) %>%  # This would show the top 10 teams
  ungroup()

p <- ggplot(df1, aes(rank, group = Team, 
                     fill = as.factor(Team), color = as.factor(Team))) +
  geom_tile(aes(y = value/2,
                height = value,
                width = 0.9), alpha = 0.8, color = NA) +
  geom_text(aes(y = 0, label = paste(Team, " ")), vjust = 0.2, hjust = 2) +
  geom_text(aes(y=value,label = Value_lbl, hjust=0)) +
  coord_flip(clip = "off", expand = FALSE) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
  scale_x_reverse() +
  guides(color = FALSE, fill = FALSE) +
  
  labs(title='{closest_state}', x = "", y = "Your Title",
       caption = "Your Caption") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0, size = 22),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),  # These relate to the axes post-flip
        axis.text.y  = element_blank(),  # These relate to the axes post-flip
        plot.margin = margin(1,1,1,4, "cm")) +
  
  transition_states(Year, transition_length = 4, state_length = 1) +
  ease_aes('cubic-in-out')

animate(p, 200, fps = 10, duration = 40, width = 800, height = 600, renderer = gifski_renderer("gganim.gif"))

anim_save("YourPath//Name.gif")
```